# Increase area for display of rendered plot

Tags: r, shiny

I render a plot in mainPanel but Shiny uses less than 50% of the vertically available space.

So I thought it might be clever to add height=100 to renderPlot. Apparently this will increase the height of the rendered plot but won't increase the display area / iframe.

How can I influence how much space (vertically) is used by Shiny to display a rendered plot?

[image]

Here are some excerpts of the code to illustrate the technical context.

from UI-code:

```
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("line plot", plotOutput("line_plot")),
    [...]
  )
)
```

from Server-code:

```
output$line_plot <- renderPlot({
  [...]
  gg <- ggplot([...]) + geom_line() 
  print(gg)
}, height=1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# modify styling for responsible class
largerDisplay <- HTML('.shiny-plot-output {min-height:800px; max-height:800px}</style>')

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("R Big Pivot"),
  sidebarPanel(
    [...]
  ),

  mainPanel(

  # include the styling
  tags$head(largerDisplay),
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("line plot", plotOutput("line_plot")),
      [...]
    )
  )
))
```

[image]